# Nesting Cascading lists/Subtypes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, domains, widget, subtype

Has anyone got any experience in creating nested cascading lists/subtypes in QGIS? (QGIS - 3.22.10-Białowieża)

I am trying to create a form that allows user to select a type of survey from a list, then chose catogeries from within that survey and finally a correlating code.

However, while the use of the "relation, query" widget works for the first section (Survey to Category), the cascade list fails to populate for the second section (Category to Code). Failing to populate the list at all.

[image]

**[Value relation widget in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370398/value-relation-widget-in-qgis)**

The filter expressions for both the Survey to Category & Category to Code are set up using the current_value expression as demonstrated in the above post.

[image: Survey to Class]

[image: Class to Code]

Comment: Does this still persist in 3.28.x ?

Comment: Could you provide your tables LandcoverClasses and LandcoverTypesLU?