# Cascading drop down list only recognizes first item in the drop down list

Tags: qgis, dropdownlist

I set up a cascading drop down list using 4 forest type categories: Hardwood, Hardwood Pine, Pine Hardwood, Pine. I used a Keyfield FTClass: HD, HP, PH, PN. I set up a CSV table with the categories FTCat that match the classification keyfield. Using a Value Relation, In the layer properties of Attribute Form, I set the FTClass attribute with FTClass as the key and FTCat as the Value from the CSV table. This works fine when editing the layer. I want to use these categories to filter a list of 75 specific Forest Types. I built a CSV lookup table that list all the forest types associated with the respective FTCat and FTClass attributes.  I used this table and setup a Value Relation using FTClass as the keyfield and ForestType as the Value from the look up table . I also used the filter expression FTCLASS=current_value ('FTCat') to filter the forest types to only those in the respective categories. The FTCat drop down works fine, but the ForestType drop down shows the appropriate list of forest type and I can select the appropriate forest type, but QGIS only keeps the first forest type in the list, not the selected one upon saving.

Any ideas why the select item is not accepted into the field?

I am new to QGIS.

Comment: If you identify this as a duplicate, please do so via the `close` button, not a link-only answer to the first Question [Value relation widget in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370398/value-relation-widget-in-qgis)

Answer (score 0):

A good explanation and resolution was presented in a previous post:
[Value relation widget in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370398/value-relation-widget-in-qgis)